# HTTP request timeout and content download time

Tags: javascript, http, networking, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a weird issue about HTTP requests...
The request is marked as "Pending" under the network and eventually a timeout happens. The timing tab shows this

[image: First request]

The weird thing about this is that if I execute the **exact, same** HTTP request a second time it gets processed in 500ms and I correctly get the requested data.

[image: Second request]

Does someone know how this can happen and how can this be fixed?
Thank you!!

Comment: What kind of back-end are you using? It can be many things.

Comment: There's NodeJS behind and a postgres DB but we're using the same engine to make many other request and all work fine. Just this one causes problem maybe due to the relatively big amount of data that it returns (1000 records from DB that are rearranged in more complex structures). What I don't understand is because the second call works flawlessy. I'd expect to find the same problem with each request if it was something back-end-related..

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining. Is the query cached in server-side when it executes the second time? The screenshot comes from Chrome I guess? What happens in other browsers?

Comment: Same happens in firefox too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are still looking for this, it happened that due to a coding error AngularJS started to trigger a huge amount of digests that blocked the client to get the HTTP response.